# What happens after paper is accepted but not yet published

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I want to know what actually happens, when a paper is accepted but not yet published. What happens in behind the scenes after I sign the copyrights.

Comment: Journal paper? Conference paper? Normally, the paper is scheduled for publication afterwards so that it eventually appears as a normal publication (there may be some fee-paying expected from you until then). In the meantime, you can list the paper as "accepted" in your CV. There is not so much formal happening. How the issue number is assigned in journals is up to them and there is no general rule. Some publishers already post the papers online before an issue number is assigned. But there is not like a standard process of what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Check the canonical post and see if there's anything specific you need to ask. [Typical workflow of a journal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a)